# Creating a shortcut to connect to my iPad over USB and extend display

Tags: ipad, display, script, monterey

I want to use the new OS Shortcuts feature to be able to push command-D on my keyboard to automatically extend my display to my iPad over USB instead of having to open System Preferences/Displays and click the drop down to connect to my iPad.

I created a script in terminal which will open the System Preferences, but I can’t get it to access the Displays settings and then how to access the drop down and select my iPad. I’d prefer to have this also close the System Preferences window after it issues the command to connect to my iPad as well. I am constantly up and back to my desk throughout the day and my iPad goes with my, but my MacBook stays on my desk, so I have to do this constantly. Small annoyance.

I tried something along the lines of

```
open "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.display"
```

I think this may have opened the display preferences (or maybe just the system preferences, sorry, I can’t remember atm), but I don’t know how to proceed from there.

*edit*

Apparently this wasn’t clear enough? I’m wanting to just run a script that will start extending my display to my iPad once it’s connected to my iPad via USB. I’ll bind it to a button combination and it will start the extended display feed to the iPad. I’ve seen that shortcuts allows you to insert terminal command scripts as input; hence my above approach. However I'm unfamiliar with the shortcuts app, so if there is an alternative method to accomplishing the same goal, I'm fine with that too. I just don’t want to have to open the System Preferences > Displays > Share to drop down menu every time I hook my iPad back up to my laptop. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for help with the shortcut in general or for the specific problem with opening a System Preferences pane?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following apple script to extend the display to your iPad.
You can then trigger the script on USB connection by a method of your liking, ex Keyboard Maestro.

This works on Sonoma 14.3.
Make sure to update NAME_OF_IPAD.

```
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
    reveal pane id "com.apple.Displays-Settings.extension"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Settings"
        delay 0.1 -- wait for UI to be ready
        tell pop up button "Add" of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Displays"
            click
            repeat until exists of menu "Add"
                delay 0.1
            end repeat
            
            click (last menu item of menu "Add" whose name contains "NAME_OF_IPAD")
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Great timing I came here a mere month after this answer was posted! Good work

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a quicker one click way to assign a shortcut to extend my iPad Pro to my MacBook Pro, instead of the 4 click process to going through system settings.
I originally got this down to two clicks, via control centre.

But still would like a one click option or even siri command to extend my iPad Pro. Be nice if Apple gave more shortcut options in the app so we could choose what we like and action it.

Answer (score 0):

@Renta You can open the Display preferences via terminal with this command:

```
open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Displays.prefPane
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Copied answer from @Rando above but with a delay loop for opening the pref pane added. Props to @Rando

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Settings"
        activate
        reveal pane id "com.apple.Displays-Settings.extension"
    end tell
    
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Settings"
            repeat until exists of pop up button "Add" of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Displays"
                delay 0.1 -- wait for UI to be ready
            end repeat
            tell pop up button "Add" of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Displays"
                click
                repeat until exists of menu "Add"
                    delay 0.1
                end repeat
                
                click (last menu item of menu "Add" whose name contains "NAME_OF_IPAD")
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    return input
end run
```